# Insert data into a list of databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, multiple-databases

I have basic knowledge of MS SQL which actually sabotages me as the syntax differs from MySQL in which I need the code written.

I have X databases named "project_%". It's 1 database per project. I need a script or a procedure (it's gonna be rarely used by support) that's gonna take some user info from master DB and add a list of users (or at least a single user) into all (later a list might be required) "project_%" databases.

My idea was to create a variable/temp table to fill with the list of databases and run a cycle (for/while) to set a default schema and insert required data. This is where I'm stuck as I have no idea how to set default schema from a variable or to input the variable into `variable_db`.table.

What I've found so far always differed from what I needed and couldn't apply it to my code.

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using Python, you might use a package called [alphadb](https://github.com/w-kuipers/alphadb). It allows you to create so called `version source templates` in JSON that you can apply to a database. In this version template you can define `default data` for tables.

In Python you could then loop over you databases and apply it to all of them:

```py
from alphadb import AlphaDB
import json

databases = ["db1", "db2", "db"]

for db in databases:
  
    adb = AlphaDB()

    adb.connect(
        "host": "your-host",
        "user": "your-user",
        "password": "your-password",
        "database": db,
    )
    
    with open("path/to/version/source") as vs:
        version_source = json.loads(vs.read())

    adb.update(version_source)
```

Do refer to the [official documentation](https://alphadb.w-kuipers.com) for setting up the database. This will not just work with an already populated database as it has to be configured first.